# Firebase function API KEY in file .env

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

I have a Firebase (1st Generation) function that consumes an API. I have the API KEY of that service in a `.env` file. It works well.

index.ts

```
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

const headers = {
  headers: {
    'X-Api-Key': API_KEY
  }
}

export const getSitesPrices = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
  const sitesPrices = await axios.get(`https://example.com/api`, headers);
  return sitesPrices.data;
});
```

.env

```
API_KEY = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

However the documentation mentions that this is not good practice ([read here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?hl=es&gen=1st#secret-manager)). It says: "...This is especially important if you check your .env files in source control."

What does this mean? How can someone access the data in a .env file? Aren't the functions supposed to run server-side?

I have tried to implement a secret manager as the documentation recommends but I have had many complications. For example, it doesn't allow me to run it with the Emulator and when I try to upload my function I get an error that the secret is only available at runtime. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anyone who has admin access to your Firebase project can find the .env file (since it participates like all other files in a deployment), which is maybe not what you expected at the time you deployed.

Comment: Thank you. I tell you that I am the only owner of the project, no one else has access. However, I have been able to verify that they can obtain my password

Comment: It's definitely up to you to choose what's best for you.  As far as "best practices" are concerned, it's definitely not a good idea to accidentally expose keys to those who haven't been explicitly granted access to them.  In the case of .env files, accidents like that can happen.